# Is there a faster way to find elements in a 2D sorted array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I wanted to ask if there is a faster way to find elements in an 2D sorted array. The 2D array is sorted alphabetically. The array contains around 900 elements. Here is an example of the data that the array contains:

```
[["Alphabit","ABC"],["ABNCoin","ABN"],["Crown","CRW'],["Cyder","CYDER"],["Agrello","DELTA"]]
```

Like you can see I have sorted alphabetically on the second value.

What I want is users can type something in the searchbar at the top and I will start searching in the array after values that match. Those matches will be showed to the person.

What I mean with matches. 
If someone typed the letter A in the searchbar, I will show the results:

- Alphabit, ABC
- ABNCoin, ABN
- Agrello, DELTA

If someone typed in the letter T in the searchbar, I will show the results:

- Agrello, DELTA
- Alphabit, ABC

So what I mean if one of the 2 values have the letter in it I will show it. 
The HTML data is already in the HTML. And they have matching I values like in the array:

This is my JQuery code that I have:

```
var searchAfterCoin = function () {
    var data = $('#searchBar').val().toLowerCase();
    if (data === '' || data === ' ') {
        showEverthing(searchArrayOfNames.length);
    }
    else {
        hideEverthing(searchArrayOfNames.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < searchArrayOfNames.length; i++) {
            var longName = searchArrayOfNames[i][0].toLowerCase();
            var shortName = searchArrayOfNames[i][1].toLowerCase();
            if (longName.indexOf(data) >= 0 && shortName.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
                $("#" + i + "").show();
            }
            else {
                if (longName.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
                    $("#" + i + "").show();
                }
                else {
                    if (shortName.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
                        $("#" + i + "").show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is an example of the HTML code I have:

```
    <div class="row" id="13"> // some Data in here// </div>
```

Like you can see the index of the matching value in the array matches the id in the HTML.

Is there away to use a faster algorithm to find the elements?
Is the method with hiding and showing the elements not fast enough or is it better to create the html when he starts to search and append it to the html then?

Comment: `Like you can see the value in the array matches the id in the HTML.` - the id in your html is `13` and none of the elements in your array have a value anything like that. Did you mean *index* in the array?

Comment: Yes I mean the index. 13 was just an example because the length of my array is 892

Comment: maybe you can addapt this to your case  
 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure about better algorithm, but you can certainly make your code shorter and simpler.

```
var matches = searchArrayOfNames.reduce(function(p,c,i){
        if(c[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(data)>-1 || c[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(data)>-1) 
           p.push(i.toString())
        return p;
},[]);
$('div.row').filter(function(){
    return matches.indexOf(this.id)>-1;
}).show();
```

The concept here is to use `reduce` to find the indexes of elements matching the input and then jquery `filter` to find the elements based on this `matches` array.

```js
var searchArrayOfNames = [["Alphabit","ABC"],["ABNCoin","ABN"],["Crown","CRW"],["Cyder","CYDER"],["Agrello","DELTA"]];


var searchAfterCoin = function () {

    var data = $('#searchBar').val().toLowerCase();
    if (data === '' || data === ' ') {
        showEverthing(searchArrayOfNames.length);
    }
    else {
        hideEverthing(searchArrayOfNames.length);
        var matches = searchArrayOfNames.reduce(function(p,c,i){
            if(c[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(data)>-1 || c[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(data)>-1) 
               p.push(i.toString())
            return p;
        },[]);
        $('div.row').filter(function(){
            return matches.indexOf(this.id)>-1;
        }).show();       
    }
};
$('#searchBar').on('keyup',searchAfterCoin)

function showEverthing(){
    $('div').show();
}

function hideEverthing(){
    $('div').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input id="searchBar" type="text" />
 
 <div class="row" id="0"> Alphabit data </div>
 <div class="row" id="1"> ABNCoin data </div>
 <div class="row" id="2"> Crown data </div>
 <div class="row" id="3"> Cyder data </div>
 <div class="row" id="4"> Agrello data </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out! It works much faster! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
 var searchArrayOfNames = [["Alphabit", "ABC"], ["ABNCoin", "ABN"], ["Crown", "CRW"], ["Cyder", "CYDER"], ["Agrello", "DELTA"]];

 /* creating li for each choices ...*/
 searchArrayOfNames.forEach((e, i) => {
  $(`<li id="choice-${i}">${e.join(', ')}</li>`).appendTo($('#choices'));
 });

 /* THE CODE, you need to look into .... */
 $("#searchBar").on('change keydown paste input', function (event) {
  var searchText = ($('#searchBar').val() || '').toLowerCase();
  
  searchArrayOfNames.forEach((names, i) => {
   // if search text is null/empty/undefined or any text in a row matches, then show...
   // else hide ..
   (!searchText || names.some((name) => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1))
   ? $(`#choice-${i}`).show()
   : $(`#choice-${i}`).hide();
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="searchBar"/>
<ul id="choices"></ul>
```

Comment: What is names? I have 2 values that I need to look after it can match with 2 values.

Comment: names is an element on the outer array Eg: `["Alphabit","ABC"]`

Comment: @Steven [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) evaluates until a truth value is met. When it meets a truth value it stops evaluting elements further.

Comment: It need to continue because like in the example I gived it can match multiple items.

Comment: @Steven demoed it .. u can see how it performace, by increasing your data horizontally or vertically ...

Comment: I have tried it works in browers. But it don't work in android webview and that is where I need it. It gives syntax errors in android webview. But thanks for trying!